# Alter php.ini include path, Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, command-line, php

I've looked at every question that has been asked on this so far, and none have helped.  Partially, this is because in all these years, I've avoided learning the in depth how-to's of php.ini manipulation.  (other than errors and other basic changes).

I'm running Windows 7, and I installed Zend Framework to c:\wamp.  thus far, I've opened my php.ini file, and changed it to the following:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library"
```

When I try to run zf in the command line, I get an error, "In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework is inside your include path".

I have also added a user variable to my environment variables

```
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH  set to C:\wamp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library
```

At this point, I'm basically stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Am I including the path wrong in the php.ini file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to uncomment the include line. (Remove semi-colon at the start of the line)

`include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library"`

instead of

`;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\wamp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library"`

Comment: Figured it would be something like this. Thank you.  All my material says to alter the path, but no real specific instructions on how...

Answer (score 2):

When a line in an INI file begins with ";", it denotes a comment and is not parsed. Simply remove that, and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

Also you can add zend path and php path in environment variable

Stpes:
Go to My computer -> right click ->select properties -> Click on change settings->click on advance ->click on environment variales-> go to system vaiable -. edit path -> add your php and zend path here